# how can remove all of the protection for all of user in google sheet script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, privileges

I have a Sheet which only columns `A-C` I want to share with user1, and only columns `F-H` to user2. I do this work with Apps Script. Neither user1 nor user2 are the owner. To execute some code I have to delete all the protection for all users. I wrote the code below for this, but it only works for the owner and not for other users.

```js
function onOpen (e){
var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var range1 = s1.getRange('A:A');
var range2 = s1.getRange('B:J');
var range3 = s1.getRange('K:Z');
var range4 = s1.getRange('AA:AC');
var range5 = s1.getRange('AD:AE');
var range6 = s1.getRange('A1:AE1');  
var protection1 = range1.protect().setDescription('1');
var protection2 = range2.protect().setDescription('2');
var protection3 = range3.protect().setDescription('3');
var protection4 = range4.protect().setDescription('4');
var protection5 = range5.protect().setDescription('5');
var protection6 = range6.protect().setDescription('6');   
protection1.removeEditors(protection1.getEditors());
protection2.removeEditors(protection2.getEditors());
protection3.removeEditors(protection3.getEditors());
protection4.removeEditors(protection4.getEditors());
protection5.removeEditors(protection5.getEditors());
protection6.removeEditors(protection6.getEditors());  
protection1.addEditor('rafi@gmail.com'); 
protection1.addEditor('naseri@gmail.com');   
protection2.addEditor('sabeti@gmail.com');
protection2.addEditor('chavoshi@gmail.com');
protection2.addEditor('naseri@gmail.com');
protection3.addEditor('naseri@gmail.com');
protection3.addEditor('rezvani@gmail.com');
protection3.addEditor('nurian@gmail.com');
protection3.addEditor('fazeli@gmail.com');
protection4.addEditor('naseri@gmail.com');
protection5.addEditor('naseri@gmail.com');
protection5.addEditor('nurian@gmail.com');
protection5.addEditor('fazeli@gmail.com');
protection5.addEditor('rezvani@gmail.com');  
protection6.addEditor('chavoshi@gmail.com');
protection6.addEditor('naseri@gmail.com');  
if (protection1.canDomainEdit()) {
protection1.setDomainEdit(false);
}
if (protection2.canDomainEdit()) {
protection2.setDomainEdit(false);
}
if (protection3.canDomainEdit()) {
protection3.setDomainEdit(false);
}
if (protection4.canDomainEdit()) {
protection4.setDomainEdit(false);
}
if (protection5.canDomainEdit()) {
protection5.setDomainEdit(false);
}
if (protection6.canDomainEdit()) {
protection6.setDomainEdit(false);
}
}  



}
function onEdit(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
var r = s.getActiveRange(); 

if(s.getName() == "Order List" && r.getColumn() == 30 && r.getValue() == true) {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Arrived Complete");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}

var s10 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
var protections = s10.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
var protection = protections[i];
if (protection.canEdit()) {  
protection.remove();
}  
} 

onOpen (e);  
}


function clearFormat() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = s.getActiveSheet();
var sheetname = ss.getName();
var s2c = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss2cc = s2c.getActiveSheet();
var sheetname = ss2cc.getName();
if (sheetname == "Arrived Complete") {
ss.clearConditionalFormatRules();
}
if (sheetname == "Arrived Canceled") {
ss2cc.clearConditionalFormatRules();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no direct way of doing your goal: to show certain parts of a Sheet only to some users. But there is hope to accomplish something similar, because there are two known workarounds for that:

1. One way is to [publish a webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) that checks the username (like you did in your code) and prints only the intended column.
2. Another way is to [share](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822) different Sheets with different users, with only the data that you want to show them. Each Sheet will be automatically synchronized with a *master sheet* that joins all of them together; but only the administrator will access it.

As you can see, these are two close workarounds. I hope that they work for you. Don't hesitate to write back with any question or doubt.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. I chose the second solution because I tried the first one in different ways but it didn't work out.